# How to add captcha to amplify ui?

Tags: angular, aws-amplify

I need a captcha to be shown in amplify angular ui. But I couldn't find a document on how to add it. Added these code in my angular app and did all the configuration in aws and all is working fine, signup and signin. But I need to add a captcha bot verification in this `amplify-authenticator` but couldn't find it in their documentation.

```
<amplify-authenticator [loginMechanisms]="['email']" [signUpAttributes]="['name', 'phone_number']">
    <ng-template amplifySlot="authenticated" let-user="user" let-signOut="signOut">
        <h1>Welcome {{ user.username }}!</h1>
        <button (click)="signOut()">Sign Out</button>
    </ng-template>
</amplify-authenticator>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/usage/lambda-triggers/#custom-auth-challenge-with-google-recaptcha. I'm not sure this can be added from Amplify Studio but you can have a try with the CLI.

Comment: Didn't worked. Not able to add the captcha. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try customizing the sign up fields with your own captcha component. This example on the UI site shows adding an acknowledgement checkbox. https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/angular/connected-components/authenticator/customization#sign-up-fields